# Given coordinates of vertices of triangle. Find bisector.

Tags: geometry

The vertices of triangle $ABC$ Euclidian space $\Bbb R^2$ are $A=(2,1),\, B=(0,7)$ and $C=(5,-10)$. Write down equation of bisector of angle $\angle A$.

I know that bisector intersects line $BC$ at some point $M$. Therefore $\dfrac{BM}{BC}=\dfrac{AB}{AC}$. Then we can somehow find coordinates of $M$, and from there we should find the equation.

Could you please explain how can I solve this task? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should have $\dfrac {BM}{\color{red}MC} = \dfrac {AB}{AC}$ instead.

Once we find this ratio, we can use the segment formula:

$$M = \left(\frac {tx_1+sx_2}{s+t}, \frac {ty_1+sy_2}{s+t}\right)$$

if $BM : MC = s:t$ and $B = (x_1,y_1), C = (x_2,y_2)$.